# Difference in the same tag version of material-ui between GitHub and NPM repo

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm looking at the tarball for Material UI version 1.5.1 and then found out that there are two tarballs available for Material UI with regard to version 1.5.1. When I pick up the same file from two tarballs, there are some differences.

One tarball is from NPM registry

```
   "@material-ui/core": {
         "version": "1.5.1",
         "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@material-ui/core/-/core-1.5.1.tgz",
   }
```

The other tarball is from Material UI Github:

```
https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/archive/v1.5.1.tar.gz
```

When I pick up the same file from both tarballs(core-1.5.1.tgz and v1.5.1.tar.gz) above, for example, 'createMixins.js', there are some differences.

So my question is why files under the same version differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tarball on GitHub is the original source code. The tarball on npm has had some babel transformations applied to make the code more compatible with different JavaScript environments.

Here is the `createMixins.js` from GitHub (v1.5.1):

```
export default function createMixins(breakpoints, spacing, mixins) {
  return {
    gutters: (styles = {}) => {
      return {
        paddingLeft: spacing.unit * 2,
        paddingRight: spacing.unit * 2,
        ...styles,
        [breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
          paddingLeft: spacing.unit * 3,
          paddingRight: spacing.unit * 3,
          ...styles[breakpoints.up('sm')],
        },
      };
    },
    toolbar: {
      minHeight: 56,
      [`${breakpoints.up('xs')} and (orientation: landscape)`]: {
        minHeight: 48,
      },
      [breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
        minHeight: 64,
      },
    },
    ...mixins,
  };
}
```

Here is the same from the npm tarball:

```
"use strict";

var _interopRequireDefault = require("@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault");

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.default = createMixins;

var _defineProperty2 = _interopRequireDefault(require("@babel/runtime/helpers/defineProperty"));

var _extends3 = _interopRequireDefault(require("@babel/runtime/helpers/extends"));

function createMixins(breakpoints, spacing, mixins) {
  var _toolbar;

  return (0, _extends3.default)({
    gutters: function gutters() {
      var styles = arguments.length > 0 && arguments[0] !== undefined ? arguments[0] : {};
      return (0, _extends3.default)({
        paddingLeft: spacing.unit * 2,
        paddingRight: spacing.unit * 2
      }, styles, (0, _defineProperty2.default)({}, breakpoints.up('sm'), (0, _extends3.default)({
        paddingLeft: spacing.unit * 3,
        paddingRight: spacing.unit * 3
      }, styles[breakpoints.up('sm')])));
    },
    toolbar: (_toolbar = {
      minHeight: 56
    }, (0, _defineProperty2.default)(_toolbar, "".concat(breakpoints.up('xs'), " and (orientation: landscape)"), {
      minHeight: 48
    }), (0, _defineProperty2.default)(_toolbar, breakpoints.up('sm'), {
      minHeight: 64
    }), _toolbar)
  }, mixins);
}
```